# How do you use the contents of a list literally, rather than using it as a 'list'? ; TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Tags: python

I currently have the following (generalized) code, where I am trying to increase  `counter` if `list_1[list_2[i]]` is equal to 3. I want `list_1[list_2[i]]` to return the element at index `list_2[i]` in `list_1`. However, list_2 is full of lists which contain coordinates, like `(4,7)`, meaning that when I run this code, I get the following error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

My goal is to have `list_1[list_2[i]]` return something like (0, 0), so that my if statement becomes `if array[0, 0] == 3:`

```
import numpy as np

for item in list_1:
    i = 0
    counter = 0

    while i < len(item):
        if array[list_1[list_2[i]]] == 3:
            counter += 1
```

To put it simply (since I realize how poor an explanation above is), if I have `list_1` with multiple parameters of its own, how can I treat its contents literally, such that `list_2d[list_1]` becomes `list_2d[1, 2]`, without unpacking `list_1` into separate variables?

```
list = [1, 2]
list_2d = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]

print(list_2d[list])
```

> Hope for output:

```
5
```

> Actual output:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Comment: What are you asking? The error message is quite clear,  `list indices must be integers or slices, not list`

Comment: Note, `list_2d[1, 2]` would be an error as well